# Program crashes - divide by 0

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I have question about running a program on different computers.

I wrote a program with C++\windows 7 64 bit\visual studio that works perfect on my computer.

When I tried to run it on another computer (windows 7 64 bit\visual studio) the program crashed - it says I divided by 0 some variable.

This is (very little) part of the code:

```
unsigned int var2;
double var1 ;

void main()
{
 // some code ...
 var1 = 1.0;
 // some more code ...
 var1 /= 2;
 ...  
 var2 /= var1;
}
```

Right after the last line the program crashes...

I understand that the two variables are from different kind, but I will be happy to know why the code runs perfect on one machine and crashes on the other and how can I prevent this.

**edit:** I get this warning-

Warning 7 warning C4244: '/=' : conversion from 'double' to 'u_int', possible loss of data

Thanks!

Comment: The program ***crashes***.

Comment: `var2` is not even initialized... why is that?

Comment: Are you sure the problem has to do with only the parts of the code you're showing? Did you try using `gdb`?

Comment: Im sorry, it does initialized, and changes during the code.. I didnt mention this..

Comment: Your program does not compile. Please provide a minimal AND compilable testcase.

Comment: You can prevent crash by not doing the division. If you need some other solution then please write program that compiles here and tell what is the outcome of it that you desire.

Comment: I am sure this is the line.. I havent tried using gdb. I am kind of new with it and not familiar with it yet..

Comment: Have you tried debug before `va2/=var1`? What are the values of the two? Try a simple example as you showed here, does it crash too?

Comment: If the problem is really as simple as you describe, it should be easy to make a compilable source file rather than the incomplete snippet you show here. Then tell us which compiler works and which one crashes.

Comment: When your program works on one system but crashes on another, it's a typical sign of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). One way of finding places where your code does something unexpected is to enable more warnings, as warning messages often points to places where you're doing something you maybe shouldn't be doing.

Comment: provide intermediate code instead of *...*

Comment: The fact that it doesn't crash on your computer doesn't mean it "works perfect"; depending on the initial value of `var2` and the intermediate code you snipped, you've likely invoked some form of undefined behavior (unless VS explicitly lists `void main()` as a legal signature for `main`, you already have).  Step through the code with your debugger line by line and examine the values of your variables as you go.

Comment: @PhistucK : to be precise, unlike a local variable, a global variable is always initialised. It is zero intialised if it is defined without an initialisation expression. So, in its example, `var2` and `var1` are set to zero.

Answer (score 3):

> Warning 7 warning C4244: '/=' : conversion from 'double' to 'u_int',
>   possible loss of data

This probably refers to the last line of the program, where you try to divide an int with a double. The double at this point holds the value `0.5`, which will be rounded down (or rather cut off) to `0` when converted to an int. This results in the division by zero.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out that this is what happened. but why the program cashes on one machine and on the other one its o.k..? 
thanks.

Comment: Is it possible one machine has other optimization settings enabled? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/2b465480-6206-418d-9b3c-640c1d0dafa2/why-program-doesnt-crash-dividing-by-zero

Comment: That's the thing about breaking the rules - there's no guarantee that the program will crash with a nice clear error message. That's why it's important to listen to the warnings and avoid triggering errors in the first place.

Comment: I think the warning is here because the behaviour may be different from what expects the developper. But the expression `var2/=var1;`, as far as I understood, is correct and fully defined from the point of view of the language. Beware that the place where you debugger indicates your crash may be slightly different from the place where the bug stands

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the 'usual arithmetic conversion' in the norm, the expression shall first convert `var1` to `double`, do the arithmetic operation with the double values (so non zero ones) and then convert the result to ìnt`. So the warning does not explain the divide by 0 exception.

I think the error comes from a part of code not shown in your snapshot and probably containing an undefined behaviour (which frequently have the same code to sometimes works and sometimes crash).